# Changing an old PC laptop hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have an old (1998) Gateway Solo 2300 laptop which is missing the hard drive (I bought it like this on an auction site).

The manual says "accepts 2.5" 12.7 mm hard disk drives" but when I look inside the hard drive port in the laptop, it doesn't look like a standard IDE connector that the drive snaps into.

I don't know much about this kind of hardware (probably obvious), but my question is, can I get "any" 2.5" 12.7 mm hard drive and plug it into this laptop? If not, is a USB external drive an option? The laptop does have 2 USB ports.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to update my post - I just found some trays for the Gateway 2300 Solo, so it looks like all I need is a 2.5" 12.7 mm IDE hard drive, but it doesn't matter what size.

If I'm mistaken I'd appreciate any feedback.

Thanks again!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but it might help when you go to [install the harddrive](http://support.gateway.com/s/Mobile/Solo_Series/p2300/p230025.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

The thing that "doesn't look like  a standard IDE connector" is just an adapter.  Just pull it off of the old hard drive and put it on the new one.

**EDIT:**

You say you don't have your old hard drive.  It probably had one of these (or something similar) on it.  Google "Gateway Hard Drive Caddy" and see what comes up.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I should have explained I don't have the original hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the correct type of interface for the drive.  Most of the drives sold now are SATA, which have a different connector.

You need to find a drive with an EIDE/ATA-3, which may be tricky to find.  You may have to resort to eBay to find them, I didn't see any with a quick search of Amazon.